# how do i create a contact in iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone

I want to duplicate the functionality you see when you tap and hold a phone # in an email.  You see a menu pop up and 2 of the options are "Create new contact" & "Add to existing contact".  After selecting a contact, you then have a contact with the phone number displayed and can further edit the contact in the contact edit page.  Try tapping and holding a phone # to see what I'm getting at.

Anyway, I'm not sure how to do this.  I can create a contact via the SDK, but not sure how to display the contact edit screen pre-populated with the phone number.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'd start with the section of the [Address Book Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/400-UI_Controllers/UI_Controllers.html) on the view controllers furnished by the system. Beyond that, perhaps you could post the code you're having trouble with?